# How to get the URL of a WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, string, url, webbrowser-control

```
        if (webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri == "www.google.com")
        {
            label9.Text = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri;
        }
```

This is my current code. When I press the button to run this I get the error.

Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

And I don't know why it does that or how to fix it. Any help will be great.

Also It have to work in a timer so that it can be checked.

Comment: Provide some details: type of exception, line number. Where do you call the code above (event handler, constructor) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably your `webBrowser1.Url` is `null`
try below to get url

```
    string url = "";
    if (webBrowser1.Url != null)
    {
        url = webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    }
    if (url == "www.google.com")
    {
        label9.Text = url;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Url` Property will remain `null` untill the control is rendered so use this:

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e) {
     if (webBrowser1.Url.ToString() == "www.google.com") {
          label9.Text = webBrowser1.Url.ToString();
     }
}
```

And in your button `Click` event add:

```
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
```

Comment: how would i implement that into a timer?

Comment: In your button click event handler register DocumentCompleted

Answer (score 0):

Well you didn't set any url (no page is loaded inside the web browser). You could try this:

webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.google.com", UriKind.Absolute);

And get the url this way: webBrowser1.Url.ToString();

Wait for the page to load and the press then button.

Answer (score 0):

I thought id comment on this, I literally took your

```
"webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri;"
```

and in my case im using a combotextbox so Double click your browser form and it will take you to the even handler, i just put

```
"combobox1.text= webBrowser1.Url.AbsoluteUri;"
```

and it works for me now. You got me on the time, but whatever you need to check, check for the combobox1.text or whatever you are using for your url's

Answer (score 0):

if your browser1 is chromiumwebbrowser, then use

```
    string url = browser1.Address;
```

call the url and you will get it.